# How many unique ways can I deal a deck of cards which has repeating cards?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, card-games

I have a card game which has 7 type of unique cards for a total of 21. The structure of the deck is the following:

- card A: 2x
- card B: 2x
- card C: 2x
- card D: 3x
- card E: 3x
- card F: 4x
- card G: 5x

At the start of the game the deck is shuffled and 1 card is discarded. Then, the 2 players are dealt 6 cards each. Then, the player who starts draws a card.

I am looking for each unique combinations of cards player 1 can have in their hands after they draw a card.

Comment: You can ignore the discard and Player $2$.  You just want the unique combinations of $7$ cards in Player $1$'s hand from the $21$ originally.  There will be a solution using generating functions

Comment: You are right. For this I get 910 possible combinations. With the following python code:

    len(set(itertools.combinations('AABBCCDDDEEEFFFFGGGGG', 7)))